# Failed to Load workflow- SP Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I am using Sharepoint Designer 2007. I cannot add new workflow or amend existing workflow. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2. I have tried the following post. But I cannot get the directory specified.

Other users can access the workflow, but it happens only for me.

[Tried This Link](https://www.mriwm.com/Public/PamBlog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=11)

Did anyone have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your office 2007 with the latest Microsoft patches. I remember having this problem before but don't remember how I fixed it! :(